# How do you make your date appear in DD/MM/YY format with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I've tried various answers to other questions and looked through my notes, but I'm still struggling to make this work. I want the current date to appear on my page in the format dd/mm/yyyy. So for example if I was on the page today it would read 02/11/2014 and tomorrow it would read 03/11/2014 etc.

This is the current code I've been fiddling around with, but its not working for me. I'm clearly overlooking something but I can't figure out what. Would be great if someone could help me out, I understand this is probably something very simple but my brain has gone to mush haha!

```
<div id="date">

<script type="text/javascript">

var currentTime;

currentTime = new Date ();

var thisDate = currentTime.getDate();
var thisMonth = currentTime.getMonth(); 
var thisYear = currentTime.getFullYear();

document.write(date +  month +       year);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

date, month and year arent declared in your code, you should use the right variables.

```
var thisDate = currentTime.getDate();
var thisMonth = currentTime.getMonth(); 
var thisYear = currentTime.getFullYear();

document.write(thisDate + '/' +  thisMonth + '/' + thisYear);
```

Comment: Thanks @Hatsjoem, this didn't work unfourtnatly, I put that code into my script instead of what I had